# Laravel-Nova license on production

Tags: laravel-nova

I've bought a single license for Nova. I've downloaded it via composer and both localy-served and on my staging server the app runs fine.

I'm wondering, what I'd have to do concerning the Nova license to deploy the whole application to a production environment? How does Nova know that it's my license? And which one? Because I want to purchase a second license for a second website, but how does Nova differentiate between the licenses? Or is that just a matter of confidence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't really monitor it as far as i'm aware.
We use the same license for dev, staging and production environments.

As of April 2022 Nova 4 has been released and the licencing has changed a bit.
https://nova.laravel.com/#pricing
Now you can buy a unlimited license for as many projects as you like. This is a one time payment which includes updates for 1 year.